# custom keyboard - wrong numeric input

Tags: android, xml, keyboard, ascii

I've made a custom keyboard for my Samsung S8. The keyboard.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard n1:keyWidth="13.999998%p" n1:keyHeight="40.0dip" n1:horizontalGap="2.6000023%p" n1:verticalGap="10.0dip"
  xmlns:n1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Row n1:keyHeight="0.100000024px" n1:rowEdgeFlags="top" />
    <Row>
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="49" n1:keyEdgeFlags="left" n1:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="50" n1:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="51" n1:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="52" n1:keyLabel="4" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="53" n1:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="54" n1:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="55" n1:keyLabel="7" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="56" n1:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="57" n1:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key n1:keyWidth="8.7%p" n1:horizontalGap="1.05%p" n1:codes="48" n1:keyLabel="0" />
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

(I omitted the other rows, only the first one is included in the code).

When I tap on the keyboard numbers, instead of writing "1", "2", and so on, I get the ASCII circled numbers, such as "❶", "❷" and so on. How could that happen? The ASCII codes are correct (48, 49, and so on).

Of course this bug happens only with the custom keyboard, not with the Samsung S8 default one.

How can I fix this issue?